# How do iOS processes get their name?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Is there a default way iOS names
Them? I'm trying to find some sort of pattern to link them to an app name/bundleID so I can retrieve that apps information from the App Store search API. From what I've seen many apps process names are simply their name (eg Dropbox, Skype) but I figure someone has a better idea

Comment: Hi jfisk! Did you ever manage to find pertinent results through the Search API? This approach is not very reliable for me so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `Info.plist` of the App, the relevant key-pair name is `CFBundleExecutable`.

The default value is set to the Xcode project name (naturally, eg "Dropbox", "Skype", etc). Look at any app's `Info.plist` via Xcode or by opening up a packaged app.

Documentation for `${EXECUTABLE_NAME}`: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW71

Source: I built [iHasApp](http://www.ihasapp.com), an app-detection framework, so I spent a lot of time looking into what you're interesting in doing.